# Are there any parliaments with more than two chambers?

Tags: parliament

All parliaments that I know off are either [unicameral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicameralism) or [bicameral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicameralism). Wikipedia has articles on [tricameral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricameralism) and even [tetracameral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetracameralism) parliaments. Do any such multicameral parliaments presently exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [List of national legislatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_legislatures) on Wikipedia it does not look like there is any country left that has more than two chambers.